# Python socket and threading won't receive message

Tags: python

I am trying to make a chat service, but my GUI won't receive the message's I send. I can connect to the server but do when I send a message I do not have the message be broadcasted. We are also trying to do multiple chat rooms but I am not sure how to do that with sockets.

When I connect in to the server it will ask for my name and broadcast that I have joined the chat but then any message I send that isn't {quit} doesn't get broadcasted. I am not sure if it is the send portion or the receive portion that is causing the issue. Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

```
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread


def accept_incoming_connections():
"""Sets up handling for incoming clients."""
    while True:
        client, client_address = SERVER.accept()
        print("%s:%s has connected." % client_address)
        client.send(bytes("Greetings from SlackChat! Now type your name and press enter!", "utf8"))
        addresses[client] = client_address
        Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client,)).start()


def handle_client(client):  # Takes client socket as argument.
"""Handles a single client connection.""" 

name = client.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
welcome = 'Welcome %s! If you ever want to quit, type {quit} to exit.' % name
client.send(bytes(welcome, "utf8"))
msg = "%s has joined the chat!" % name
broadcast(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
clients[client] = name

while True:
    msg = client.recv(BUFSIZ)
    if msg != bytes("{quit}", "utf8"):
        broadcast(msg, name+": ")
    else:
        client.send(bytes("{quit}", "utf8"))
        client.close()
        del clients[client]
        broadcast(bytes("%s has left the chat." % name, "utf8"))
        break


def broadcast(msg, prefix=""):  # prefix is for name identification.
"""Broadcasts a message to all the clients."""

for sock in clients:
    sock.send(bytes(prefix, "utf8")+msg)


clients = {}
addresses = {}

HOST = ''
PORT = 33000
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

SERVER = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
SERVER.bind(ADDR)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SERVER.listen(5)
    print("Waiting for connection...")
    ACCEPT_THREAD = Thread(target=accept_incoming_connections)
    ACCEPT_THREAD.start()
    ACCEPT_THREAD.join()
    SERVER.close()
```

GUI code:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
from socket import AF_INET, socket, SOCK_STREAM
from threading import Thread


def receive():
"""Handles receiving of messages."""
    while True:
        try:
            msg = client_socket.recv(BUFSIZ).decode("utf8")
            list2.insert(tkinter.END, msg)
        except OSError:  # Possibly client has left the chat.
            break
def send(event=None):  # event is passed by binders.
"""Handles sending of messages."""
    msg = message_text.get()
    message_text.set("")  # Clears input field.
    client_socket.send(bytes(msg, "utf8"))
    if msg == "{quit}":
        client_socket.close()
        window.quit()
def on_closing(event=None):
"""This function is to be called when the window is closed."""
    message_text.set("{quit}")
    send()
def Create_command():
    pass
def clear_command():
    message_text.set("")



window=tkinter.Tk() # TK method that creates a windows objective
window.wm_title("Zlack Chat")

l1=tkinter.Label(window, text="Chat Rooms")                  # chat room label
l1.grid(row=0,column=0, columnspan = 2, pady = 10)

l2=tkinter.Label(window, text="Chat")                                  # chat list label
l2.grid(row=0,column=3, columnspan = 2)

l3=tkinter.Label(window, text="Create Chat Room")                  # create chat room label
l3.grid(row=3,column=0, pady = (10,0))

l4=tkinter.Label(window, text="Message")                               
# message label
l4.grid(row=3,column=3, sticky = tkinter.W, padx= 10, pady = (10,0))

# Display Titles# Display text entry fields          
textvariable=Chat_rooms_text,
Chat_rooms_text=tkinter.StringVar()
list1=tkinter.Listbox(window, width=45, height = 20)                                           
# chat room list box
list1.grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan = 2, padx = (10,0))

create_text=tkinter.StringVar()
e3=tkinter.Entry(window,textvariable=create_text, width=25)             # create chat name entry
e3.grid(row=3 , column=1, pady = (10,0), sticky = tkinter.E)

message_text=tkinter.StringVar()
message_text.set("Enter your message here.")
e4=tkinter.Entry(window,textvariable=message_text, width = 70)          # message entry 
e4.grid(row=3, column=3, columnspan = 2, sticky = tkinter.E, pady = (10,0))
e4.bind("<Return>", send)

# display listbox and attached a Scrollbar
list2=tkinter.Listbox(window, width = 80, height = 20)                                           
# message feed/history
list2.grid(row=1, column=3, columnspan = 2, padx = (10,0)) # we want to span across multiple rows and columns

sb1 = tkinter.Scrollbar(window)                                         # chat list scroll bar
sb1.grid(row=1, column=2, rowspan=2,     
sticky=tkinter.N+tkinter.S+tkinter.W)

list1.configure(yscrollcommand=sb1.set)
sb1.configure(command=list1.yview)

sb2 = tkinter.Scrollbar(window)
sb2.grid(row=1, column=5, rowspan=2, stick=tkinter.N+tkinter.S+tkinter.W, padx=(0,10))

list2.configure(yscrollcommand=sb2.set)
sb2.configure(command=list2.yview)

# Display Buttons
b1=tkinter.Button(window, text="Create", width=15, command=Create_command)      # create button
b1.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan = 2, sticky = tkinter.E, pady = 10)
b2=tkinter.Button(window, text="Clear", width=15, command=clear_command)        # clear button
b2.grid(row=4, column=3, pady = 10, padx = (250, 0))
b3=tkinter.Button(window, text="Enter", width= 15, command=send)       # enter button
b3.grid(row=4, column=4, sticky = tkinter.E, pady = 10)

HOST = input('Enter host: ')
PORT = input('Enter port: ')
if not PORT:
    PORT = 33000
else:
    PORT = int(PORT)

BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)

receive_thread = Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks like your server does not retain a reference to the `Thread` that it creates.

Comment: You have indentation error in `def handle_client(...`

Comment: Your code assumes it will receive a complete message like “{quit}” which *may* happen but very often *may not happen* because TCP is a stream protocol which doesn’t guarantee that what you send in one `send()` will be received in one `recv()` - so you need to handle receiving more intelligently ensuring that you don’t process Received data until you have something worth processing and then don’t throw away data you have received from the next message. This need to be able to delimit messages is why RFC protocols based on TCP have \n message terminator.